# Can I have a DoCmd method in IF statement?

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, methods, vba

I have the following VBA code for a .mdb Access file:

```
If DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT DISTINCT Max(wk_ending_dt) FROM d2s_loader_performance" < (Date()-Weekday(Date())) Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl WHERE wk_ending_dt = (Date()-Weekday(Date())-35)"
End If
```

It then highlights the following text: `"SELECT DISTINCT Max(wk_ending_dt) FROM d2s_loader_performance"` And gives the error `Compile Error: Expected Then or GoTo`.

Any ideas?  I have a Then at the end of my conditional check, and to my understanding the double quotes are just for the SQL syntax.  I'm using this `If...Then` condition to only allow record deletion if the max table date is less than the previous week's ending date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to attack it this way:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset ("SELECT DISTINCT Max(wk_ending_dt) FROM d2s_loader_performance")

If rec(0) < (Date()-Weekday(Date())) Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl WHERE wk_ending_dt = #" & (Date()-Weekday(Date())-35) & "#"
EndIf
```

I'm assuming that "(Date()-Weekday(Date())-35)" part is supposed to be a calculation, so you need to surround it with ampersands (&), and dates in Access always need to have pound signs (#) before and after them if they're true Date fields.

Comment: Works like a charm, though I don't quite understand the rec(0) logic. FWIW, `(Date()-Weekday(Date())-35)` worked as well.  Run this as a SELECT statement in Query Builder and you'll get 12/28/13.  If VBA executes both styles the same, is there a benefit to using # vs not here?

Comment: rec(0) is the first field (the only field, in this case) in the recordset.  Since your recordset returns a single field and a single record, it's easier to just use rec(0) instead of rec("Max of wk_ending_dt").  re: the # symbol, there's no benefit of using one over the other in this case, so just use whichever is most comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can execute only action querys with `DoCmd.RunSQL`. So, you can't execute `Select` statement. For more info see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx)

My approach is to using something like this:

```
Sub SqlExecute()

    Dim db As DAO.Database 
    Dim rsttemp As DAO.Recordset  
    Set db = CurrentDB
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Max(wk_ending_dt) FROM d2s_loader_performance"
    Set rsttemp = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)


    If rsttemp(0)<(Date()-Weekday(Date())) Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl WHERE wk_ending_dt #=" & (Date()-Weekday(Date())-35) & "#"
    End If
    Set rsttemp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I figured that was the issue.  Any ideas how I can accomplish what I want to, as in only perform an action subject the max date in a table?

Comment: you can use Recordset for it..just a moment, I'll find any documentation with examples for you

Comment: Looks good, though the logic of the above answer is easier for my not-so-VBA-talented mind to understand.